# Splitting datetime value out of text string with uneven length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, time-series, code-splitting

**System:** WIN10

**IDE:** MS Visual Studio COde

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source:** supplied in the example below

**Dataset:** supplied in the example below

**Ask:**

I need to split the date and time string out of a column from a data frame that has rows of uneven delimiters i.e. some with three and some with four commas.

I am trying to figure out how to strip the date and time values: `'Nov 11 2013 12:00AM'`, and '`Apr 11 2013 12:00AM'` respectively off the back of these two records in one column into a new column given the second row in the example below has fewer commas.

**Code:**

```
df['sample field'].head(2) 

4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,
2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,
```

While the below method expands the data into different columns and staggers which column houses the date, this does not work. I need the date and time (or even just date) information in one column so that I can use the date values in further analysis (for example time-series).

**Code:**

```
df['sample field'].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':['4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,','2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,']})
df
```

Use df.extract with a regex epression

```
df['Date']= df.Text.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+:[0-9A-Z]+(?=\s+\,+))')
df



 #df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M%p')
#df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] ,format='%b %d %Y %H:%M%p')
    df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])#This or even df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=('%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')) could work. Just remmeber because your time is 12AM use 12 clock hour system %I not %H and also hour 00.00 likely to be trncated, If have say11.00AM, the time will appear
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please check this piece of your code: with .info() for dtype. This solution works and I want to mark it good but this part transformed the dtype back into a string: #.dt.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M%p'). I do not think it is needed.

Comment: bravo friend! This worked beautifully as an alternate. I admit I need to read up on the regex documentation to get more familiar with it. Great job, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need `str.extract` with a regular expression.

[Regex Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/ObZoOm/1)

```
print(df)

                                              0
0  4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM
1  2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM 

df['date'] = df[0].str.extract('(\w{3}\s\d.*\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\w{2})')

df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] ,format='%b %d %Y %H:%M%p')
```

---

```
print(df)

                                              0                date
0  4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM 2013-11-11 12:00:00
1  2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM  2013-04-11 12:00:00
```

Comment: This method seems to work partially but only for those records that have dates with a single number i.e. 

> This one: 4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,
> This one: 2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM , 

but not these:
> This one: 4457-I need, this, date, Nov 1 2013 12:00AM ,
> This one: 2359-I need this, date, Apr 1 2013 12:00AM ,

Comment: @AlfredHull I just pasted those into the regex demo above and it worked, I accounted for 1 digit numbers using `\d.*`

Comment: I just re-wrote the code in VS CODE again and for line items down the list for some reason they still show concatenated. I tried IIUC's example and it fixed the single vs. double integer date issue.

Comment: I mean WWNDE's post above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use @wwnde's data :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':['4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,','2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,']})

df['Date'] = df.Text.str.strip(',').str.split(',').str[-1].str.strip()
df['Date_formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%b %d %Y %H:%M%p')

               Text                                     Date              Date_formatted
0   4457-I need, this, date, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,  Nov 11 2013 12:00AM 2013-11-11 12:00:00
1   2359-I need this, date, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,   Apr 11 2013 12:00AM 2013-04-11 12:00:00
```

Comment: thank you for getting back this approach also checks out. Thank you!